C# forms нужна помощь с выводом таблиц из БД
Я хочу вывести каждую таблицу в отдельной вкладке через tabcontrol, как мне это сделать? Я создавал вот так вот:
TabPage tabPage1 = new TabPage( "Транспорт" ); 
tabControl1.TabPages.Add( tabPage1 );
DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView;
dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
tabPage1.Controls.Add( dataGridView1 );

Можно же установить страницы в свойствах в коллекции, как к ним потом обратиться?

Вижу 22 ответа по вашей тематике, неужели ни один не помог? А так, начать стоит с того, какая именно у вас БД.
